# Convolution in Matlab with different "sampling"

Tags: matlab, convolution

I am trying to figure out how to "normalize" the convolution that Matlab does (using the "conv" operator).  If I have a rect function with spacing T and I do the convolution of that function with itself, I should get a triangle with a height of 1.  Instead, the height of the convolution depends on the spacing I use (T).  So to "normalize" it I found in other places that I need to multiply by the spacing T.  I am not sure I understand why - can anyone mathematically show me why?

Comment: The simplest would be to resample by interpolation either the signal or the filter so their spacing match. Discrete convolutions are oftentimes supposed to treat the underlying signal as if it is sampled from a continous function. Like small "local" integrals of some kind.

Comment: That was my initial thought too for unequal spacing between the two functions.  I think that would work but I feel like there should be a better solution. What I did do was just multiply by the spacing of the first input in matlab and that seemed to have worked but I am not confident it would work for every case.

Comment: There exist many more advanced methods which can be more suitable for specific cases. Actually one called "Normalized Convolution" which is nice. But I it seemed on your question that you are still quite new to signals and systems, so maybe best to start with the basics.

Comment: For a more general filter you can use "interp" or "interp2" to interpolate the filter.

Answer (score 1):

It's the difference between continuous time convolution and discrete convolution.

$$
\mathrm{Continuous:} \,\,\, \int f(x-h) g(x) \mathrm{d}x \\
\mathrm{Discrete:} \,\,\, \sum f[x-h]g[h]
$$

The sample spacing is essentially the $\mathrm{d}x$ in the convolution integral that will give you the area, so you need to scale the result of the discrete convolution by it if you want the two be the same. Otherwise, the triangle will have height $N$, where $N$ is the number of nonzero samples in the $\mathrm{rect}$ function.